# How to check if an object's properties represent a super set of another object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, lodash

Suppose we have 2 objects:

```
var foo = {
       a: 3,
       b: 'yellow',
       c: {
           d: 5,
           e: 'green'
       }
    },
    bar = {
       b: 'yellow',
       c: {
           d: 5,
           e: 'green'
       }
    };
```

What is the best way to check that `foo` contains `bar`?

I am already using Lodash in my application, so you can use functions from that library if it makes it easier. Otherwise, vanilla JS is fine.

[EDIT]

Well, let me try to explain what I mean when I use term 'contain'. I will do it in LoDash terminology.

LoDash has `_.extend` method, so that if have 2 objects:

```
var obj1 = {a:1, b:2}, 
    obj2 = {b:4, c:{d:'green', e:5}}
```

then the operation `_.extend(obj1, obj2)` will 'extend' `obj1` - it will now have the value

```
{a:1, b:4, c:{d:'green', e:5}}
```

i.e. `obj1` 'contains' `obj2` now.

Comment: Oh, it may, may it? Sounds like homework, which you really should write yourself. What did you try? Also, you need to be really precise on the meaning of "contains", because I believe I misunderstood you on the first read. For example, does `{a: {b: 1, c: 2}}` contain `{a: {b: 1}}`? Does it contain `{b: 1, c: 2}`?

Comment: @Amadan That wording does not necessarily mean that this is a homework question. Alexei could easily just be saying "I am already using Lodash in this application, so you can use functions from that library if it makes it easier. Otherwise, vanilla JS is fine."

Comment: @Alexei does the edited title accurately reflect your question? It radically changes the meaning of it, so you should clarify yourself.

Comment: @GregL: I don't mind answering homework questions - sometimes you just get stuck. I'm reacting more to the "I expect a solution to be provided for me, and I magnanimously allow you to use LoDash when you do so" tone, going contrary to the StackOverflow expectation of showing effort before asking a question. It is a perfectly valid way of addressing a student when issuing homework. (And it is not a good way to ask anonymous volunteers for help.)

Comment: @Amadan Thx, I correct my question.

Comment: @GregL Sorry for my improper tone, if you think so. My english is not very good. I've corrected the question as Amadan offered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function containsObject(parent, child) {
    return !!_.findWhere(_.flatten([parent]), child);
}

alert(containsObject(foo, bar)); // alerts "true"
```

Comment: Your solution works, but why do you use `_.flatten`? There are no nested arrays.

Comment: I just found similar & a bit cleaner way: `_.some([foo], bar)`
Thanks!

Comment: I used flatten so you could pass an array for `parent` and it would tell you whether any object in that array is a superset of the `child` object.

Comment: `lodash.findWhere` ? There is no such function in lodash.

Comment: @EmreTapcı It has been removed in version 4. It existed in [version 3](https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#findWhere), [version 2](https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#find) and [version 1](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/1.3.1/doc/README.md#_findcollection--callbackidentity-thisarg). It was an alias for `_.find` in v1 and v2.

I wrote this answer almost 6 years ago. You are right that it is no longer correct or the best way. Thank you for adding a more modern solution using Lodash. I upvoted your answer and it should probably change to being the new accepted answer now if Alexey is still around.

Answer (score 3):

`_.isMatch(foo, bar)` does the job.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isMatch

Answer (score 2):

@GregL gave a working solution for the question. It works for me. But I found similar more concise solution, so I decided to reveal it:

```
_.some([foo], bar)
```